# Jquery .on ("click",.. not binding for content injected with document.getElementById(elemid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Tags: jquery, onclick

I was hoping someone could help me with this...
I'm trying to implement a login page with ajax-loaded content.

I have a jquery function in  which executes a php script and loads the output into one of the `<div>`s inside the body. For the initial login form, which is loaded together with the whole page, the "login" button is working fine, and the authorised content is injected into the required `<div>`.

However, with this "authorised content" I'm also injecting further links and/or buttons which I'm trying to bind to jquery, eg:

```
<div class="logout_bar">
<form class="logout">
<button type="submit" id="logout_button">Logout</button>
</form>
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
$('#logout_button').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("OK");
  SubmitJQueryData('main_body','process_logout.php','');
});
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately, this handler is never bound for some reason I cannot understand. When I refresh the page, causing the whole page to reload - then everything works.

This script is added to the page after the button, so I wouldn't expect to have the issue with DOM not seeing the id. What am I missing here?

Comment: try this $( ".logout_bar" ).on( "click", "#logout_button", function() {e.preventDefault();
  alert("OK");
  SubmitJQueryData('main_body','process_logout.php','');
});

Answer (score 1):

When you insert HTML by assigning to the `innerHTML` property, `script` tags are not executed. ([Example 1](http://jsbin.com/bobaliwe/1) [source below] - We don't see the `alert`.)

As you're using jQuery, just use its `html` function instead, which *will* execute the scripts. ([Example 2](http://jsbin.com/bobaliwe/2) [source below] - We do see the `alert`.)

E.g., instead of

```
document.getElementById(elemid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

do:

```
$("#" + elemid).html(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

---

Side note:

As you're using jQuery, you don't have to use the `XMLHttpRequest` object directly. jQuery has some very handy wrappers for it. One of those is the [`load` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which retrieves content using ajax and loads it into the target elements, executing any scripts in the response (unless you use the fragment identifier).

So for instance:

```
$("selector for the target element").load("/path/to/content");
```

...will retrieve the content from `/path/to/content` and insert it into the element matched by `selector for the target element`, executing scripts as it does so.

---

Source for [example 1](http://jsbin.com/bobaliwe/1), where we don't see the `alert`:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML =
  "Setting <code>innerHTML</code> doesn't execute scripts." +
  "<script>alert('foo');</scr" + "ipt>";
</script>
```

Source for [example 2](http://jsbin.com/bobaliwe/2), where we *do* see the `alert`:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#foo").html(
  "Using jQuery's <code>html()</code> does execute scripts." +
  "<script>alert('foo');</scr" + "ipt>"
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Wow! Yes, you are right! That's what I get for blindly following tutorials online:) Cheers!